# Is there a way to unwrap multiple objects into separate UV space?

Tags: modeling, uv

In 2.8+ the multi editing is a thing - and it's awesome! But sometimes I do not want to create atlases - I just have many many objects and just want to batch-unwrap all of them in one click without having to enter edit mode on all of them one by one.

Is there a way to do that without making a custom script?

Basically I wanted to select a bunch of objects and do Smart UV Project on them and be on my way, but that does not seem to be possible (the only one that can work that way is Lightmap Pack with "Share UV Space" option unchecked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is still no built-in way to do this and you have to use a script, as described here:

[Smart UV Unwrap Multiple Objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/103195/smart-uv-unwrap-multiple-objects)

I made my own script that does that and shows up in search to make it a bit nicer than having to click "run script". Just look for "Batch Smart Unwrap".

It will create a UV map if none is present, otherwise it use the currently active one

https://gist.github.com/orels1/2405f2fbc6a3b0950b8f65881db1b567

Answer (score 0):

You could join them - In Object Mode Hold down SHIFT then Click on each object. THen SHIFT + J will join the objects, the UV unwrap

Comment: That will make them all share UV space though. I just want them to be unwrapped as if they were separate objects, but without having to click every single one of them and hit "unwrap" one by one

Comment: This link may help. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/103195/smart-uv-unwrap-multiple-objects

Comment: Yeah... the question was basically if you can do that without a custom script in the current blender release. But I guess not. Its hard to recommend doing custom scripting to pure artist people, I'll try to package it into a nice command for them I suppose.