# Each object unfolds UVs, but objects are related. How can they be independent?

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

I try to unwrap UVs to every object, but after running the script, the UVs of the previous object and the latter object are associated.

I tried to deselect UVs and objects,but Didn't solve the problem,Here is my code:

````
import bpy

Num = len(bpy.data.collections['AutoUV'].objects)  
  
for i in range(Num):

    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

    bpy.data.collections['AutoUV'].objects[i].select_set(True)

    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

    bpy.ops.uv.select_all(action='SELECT')

    bpy.ops.uv.smart_project()

    bpy.ops.uv.select_all(action='DESELECT')

    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```
````

Comment: Hi and welcome. `smart_project()` operator works on the *active* object(s) in *Edit Mode* so you'd have to make each object the active one within the loop and call the operator, I have just updated Carlo's answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/103199/ Does this help? Also see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126577/blender-2-8-api-python-set-active-object

Comment: thanks bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj ,This is the crux of the matter.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you'd like to unwrap all objects of a certain collection, just replace `for obj in selection:` by `bpy.data.collections['Collection'].objects:`. Cheers.